# Proper approach to program icon resolutions (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I am developing a python program with tk based gui. I've found several issues with icons. I have company logo (512x512) and I want to make it application icon, which works ( window topbar icon, alt-tab icon, ...) - in addtional, on windows taskbar remains default. What's the problem is that, however I scale the image, I've tried several sizes, the alt-tab icon is always blurry and ugly.

The application is not supposed to be installed (just clone and run), so I can't put several icons to /usr/share/icons (or can I?).

To be specific:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='include/images/sp.gif')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem without application being installed? I've never done such thing before so thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to d is change the size of the image using a program like fireworks by adobe. I costs a lot but if you send it to me i will send the image back in your requested size and if you want me to make a ".ico" I will do that too. That will solve blurry and ugly. I don't know about the other problem, sorry.

Comment: Your very generous, but it won't be necessary anymore. I left it with no icon I think and nobody has (supervisor and others) even noticed so far. Anyway thank you very much for that offer.